# Java. HtmlUnitDriver. Drop down Window issue

Tags: java, htmlunit

I'm using HtmlUnit in Java to deal with a DropDown Window (Java).

I tried as User skaffman suggests:

```
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
driver.get("https://...");
...................... 
WebClient client = new Webclient();
Page page = client.getPage("https://...");
HtmlSelect select = (HtmlSelect) page.getElementById(mySelectId);
HtmlOption option = select.getOptionByValue(desiredOptionValue);
select.setSelectedAttribute(option, true);
```

It does not recognize: getElementById. Eclipse recommends to swith to findElement(By.id(" ")) PLEASE HELP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with my college. The above code is correct, make sure you set javascript enabled, otherwise you will have issues with HtmlUnit

```
driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(); 
((HtmlUnitDriver) driver).setJavascriptEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are declaring the local variable to be of the type `Page` that will contain the return value from `client.getPage("https://...");`

Although it's usually good practice to develop toward the generic interface (in this case, `Page`), the generic interface does not contain the method to `getElementById(...)`.

Try changing your 4th line of code to the following:

```
HtmlPage page = client.getPage("https://...");
```

(I am assuming that the conent being returned by `client.getPage("https://...");` is of MimeType `text/html`).

You could also use `XmlPage` or `XhtmlPage`, depending on your MimeType.

If it is none of these that you are retrieving via `client.getPage("https://...");`, then you should not be attempting to call `getElementById` on a structure that does not have this as part of its API.